# Vim Argument missing after: "--remote-tab"

Tags: bash, vim, archlinux

With the last update, now in my terminal when I run `vim` I get :

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 29 2014 09:48:57)
Argument missing after: "--remote-tab"
More info with: "vim -h"
```

I was able to open vim and run vim in my terminal before. I don't know how I could fix it and if I am the only one to have this problem (specifically on Arch Linux).

Please note that I use [bash-it](https://github.com/revans/bash-it).

Comment: when you type 'vim' in terminal, you probably have an alias defined for it or another script which runs with with some other arguments.
post the output of `which vim`

Comment: @UkuLoskit: "VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4"

Comment: `which vim` => `/usr/bin/vim`

Comment: When I comment the `source $BASH_IT/bash_it.sh` in my `.bash_profile` and then run `vim` in a new terminal window, it opens `vim` in command line as expected. So I need to find what is wrong with `bash-it` that was not wrong before.

Comment: What does `type -a vim` print? (`which` doesn't have access to shell aliases.)

Comment: You say you're the only one who has this problem. Are you the only one using `bash-it`?

Comment: A `type -a vim` returns : `vim is aliased to `gvim -b --remote-tab'` and `vim is /usr/bin/vim`

Answer (score 1):

This is (arguably) a bug in `bash-it`, or perhaps just a feature with an unfortunate side effect.

And in fact there's an [open bug report](https://github.com/revans/bash-it/issues/381), apparently prompted by this question. There's a fix in the latest version (which leaves the `vim` alias in place for MacOS for some reason).

It creates an alias for the `vim` command, which expands to `gvim -b --remote-tab`.

Using `gvim` rather than `vim` means that it invokes the graphical version of `vim` rather than the default textual version.

The `-b` option sets binary mode.  The documentation says:

> -b Binary mode.  A few options will be set that makes it possible to edit a binary or executable file.

I haven't actually used it myself. It's probably mostly harmless, but I suggest reading the documentation to decide whether it's what you really want.

The `--remote-tab` is documented (in `vim --help`; I don't see it in the man page) as:

> --remote-tab[-wait][-silent]   As --remote but use tab page per file

The `--remote` option (attempts to) edit files in a Vim server; if none is available, the files are opened normally.

The problem you're running into is that unlike `vim`, `vim --remote` or `vim --remote-tab` requires one or more file name arguments.

With that alias, you can type `vim filename` and it should work correctly. without an argument, you'll see the error message you've reported.

If you want to invoke `vim` without specifying a file name, you'll need to override the alias. Since you're using bash, there are several ways to do this:

```
\vim
command vim
'vim'
```

Or you might consider disabling or modifying that alias. If you like its functionality, you can write a shell function that invokes `gvim -b --remote-tab ...` if it has filename arguments, or just `gvim` if it doesn't.

Responding to some of the comments on your question, if you want to see how the `vim` command is defined, you can use

```
type -a vim
```

(assuming you're using bash). The `which` command doesn't have access to shell functions or aliases.

Comment: What this unexplained downvote in retaliation for my flagging of another (now deleted) answer? If not, please feel free to explain how it's wrong and/or how I can improve it.

Comment: dunno why the downvote, seems a valid explanation. i originally "fixed" the bash-it bug, as it was originally overriding vim to use the mac `mvim` with `--remote-tab`, but it was clearly not enough. anyway, bash-it will no longer alias vim for gvim on anything other than mac (as Travis originally coded it), you will have to write your own custom alias if you want gvim to be aliased to vim.

Answer (score 1):

**FIX:**

It's a bug in `bash-it`. It could be solved easily. In your `~/.bash_it/aliases/custom.aliases.bash` add `alias vim='/usr/bin/vim'`

Comment: There's no need to add that alias; just delete the existing one. But this assumes the user doesn't want `vim filename` to run `gvim -b --remote-tab filename`. The drawback of the existing alias in `bash-it` is that it doesn't work when you invoke `vim` with no arguments, but if you don't do that (I rarely do), it doesn't matter much.